# Why does .Net try to log in HTTP/computername into SQL Server(Windows) when using Kerberos from Linux?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linux, kerberos, sqlclient

I am at the end of my rope and need some help.  This will probably turn out to be something simple but I have been debugging the code and reading the same web pages for so long, I probably missed it.

I am working on setting up an environment so we can run .NET Core APIs from a Linux server.  These will hit an SQL Server running on Windows for data and use Windows AD for Integrated Security.  The outfacing server is Apache with .Net running reverse proxy using the standard Kestrel.  So I have:

`client browser -> Apache(Linux) -> Kestrel(Linux) -> SQL Server (Windows Server 2016)`

Server FDQNs:

- Linux - cats6-87.it.my.company
- Windows - cats7-47.ad.my.company

I will be referring to these by short names from here on, but please note that all of the actual settings use the FDQN.  It should also be noted that these two servers are NOT in the same domain; the Win server is part of the AD while the Linux server is not.

I am able to use Kerberos to authenticate users in Apache.  This was done via the "standard" way by creating a special AD account (catadn001), setting an SPN call `HTTP/cats6-87.it.my.company`, creating a keytab, and setting up apache to use the account and tab.  I am also able to pass this login to my .Net application and the data shown in `HttpContext.User` indicates the user is authenticated.

I am trying to double-hop so the DB can be hit by the authenticated user.  I set up the environment according to every piece of documentation I could find:

- SPNs of *MSSQLSvc/cats7-47:1433*, *MSSQLSvc/cat7-47:CATS747*
- catadn001 is set to be able to delegate Kerberos for MSSQLSvc

The SQL Server log indicates the SPNs are set up correctly and running `SELECT distinct auth_scheme FROM sys.dm_exec_connections`  after logging in using Windows Authentication in SSMS from a Windows 10 machine returns KERBEROS.

Back to Linux.

Using `kinit` I am able to retrieve a ticket for HTTP/cats6-87. `klist` confirms this.

In my .Net application, I am using `Microsoft.Data.SQLClient` to try to open an Integrated Security connection in an API endpoint:

`new SqlConnection("Data Source=cats7-47;Integrated Security=True")`

As I am experimenting here, I run my test application as myself.  Before I had even tried to hit my endpoint though, I had a couple of questions:

- How would .Net know to use HTTP/cats6-87?
- How would the credentials passed in from Apache be passed along to SQL Server?

The SqlClient documentation does not mention it. In any case, from the few pages I found about Integrated Security from Linux to Windows and SQLClient, the above connection string should be enough.  So I tried it.

No joy.

The error message presented was `Login failed for user HTTP/cats6-87`.  I checked the SQL Server log and confirmed this.  My application is trying to login with the Kerberos delegation account.  I tried to search for this and every single page came back about error messages for anonymous login indicating problems with SQL Server and Kerberos.  But I had already confirmed that SQL Server was using Kerberos correctly.

So I tried stepping through the SqlClient code by using the github repo of it.  I learned a lot, particularly about how the user name is derived on Linux versus Windows (WindowsIdentity is not available) and about how annoying OOP truly is, but nothing to solve the problem and I still don't know the answer to my two questions above.

Can someone help?  How do I get my linux application to use the Kerberos delegation to log into SQL Server in Windows?

Comment: See if you can capture (tcpdump) the connection between kestrel and cats7.  There should be a 401 (need to authenticate) with requirements followed by sending proper credentials.

Comment: I have looked at this content with WireShark before.  Except for a message from SqlServer stating that the login failed for HTTP/cats6-87, there is no other useful information.  At least for me.  All the data sent by SqlClient is sent in byte packets which I don't know how to decode so I can't see what exactly it is sending to the server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that Apache stuff but... I understand you run your `SQLClient` in a process using the same Linux account as Apache (or even in the same process). Apache has a Kerberos ticket for a SPN. Hence `SQLClient` presents its existing creds - the ticket for the SPN. That's all. "Integrated Security" == SSO == use the existing Kerberos creds.

Comment: To use alternate creds -- e.g. forward a ticket obtained from a client of your app -- you would need to wrap the `SQLClient` call inside some kind of "RunAs" mechanism. Plus, configuring Kerberos to allow "double hops" is a serious security issue; Active Directory has a special "constrained delegation" feature to mitigate that but it's not portable to ther KDCs and it's pretty complex to set up.